# Is it possible to give customise input.date adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

[How to give custom style to date picker control of adaptive card for Android platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn1HZ.jpg)

Also is it possible to allow typing date on date picker on mobile with this adaptive card date control?

Comment: Hi Neetu, to assist you with this, we'll need to know more. **Where are you displaying your cards?** Are you rendering your cards within your own app? Or are you sending cards through Bot Framework or Teams or something else?

If you're rendering cards yourself, you can tweak the controls however you want. But if you're sending cards to another host, you cannot change the behavior of the controls. We can log a feature request for the functionality you want, but that's all that you can do. Let us know whether you're rendering the cards yourself or sending them to someone else!

Comment: I am displaying my cards on webchat v4 channel for Bot Framework.